# Calculating sample proportions in R using the table function

Tags: r, statistics

I've got a model with 9 covariates and below is an example of one of the tables that it used to calculate the "yes"(1) and no(0) responses of a dataset,

```
table(wbca1$y,wbca1$Adhes)
```

And the output appears as follows

[image]

How can I code this so that I get the sample proportions for each covariate so I have a new table with 10 columns each representing "yes"(1)?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please include a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
set.seed(111)
x = sample(1:9,100,replace=TRUE)
y = sample(0:1,100,replace=TRUE)
prop.table(table(y,x),margin=2)

   x
y           1         2         3         4         5         6         7
  0 0.4444444 0.2857143 0.6923077 0.4666667 0.5000000 0.4615385 0.6666667
  1 0.5555556 0.7142857 0.3076923 0.5333333 0.5000000 0.5384615 0.3333333
   x
y           8         9
  0 0.3636364 0.4615385
  1 0.6363636 0.5384615
```

Or you can simply do:

```
tab = table(y,x)

tab[2,]/colSums(tab)
        1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8 
0.5555556 0.7142857 0.3076923 0.5333333 0.5000000 0.5384615 0.3333333 0.6363636 
        9 
0.5384615
```

Comment: Great thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
tibble(x, y) %>% 
     count(x, y) %>% 
     mutate(prop = n/sum(n))
```